# Computing the CDF of the minimum of particular dependent random variables

Tags: poisson-distribution, computational-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function, extreme-value

For each $i=1,\dots,n$ let $Z_i\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda_i)$, and suppose $\{Z_i\}$ are independent. Also for each $i=1,\dots,n$, let $\{Y_{ij}\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an infinite sequence of iid random variables, where $Y_{ij}\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p_i)$. Define

$$ X_1=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{Z_i}Y_{ij}\quad\text{and}\quad{X_2}=\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_iZ_i $$

for some strictly positive scalars $\nu_i$. It's easy to show that

$$ X_1\sim\text{Poisson}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ip_i\bigg), $$

but that $X_2$ does not follow any well-known distribution (as a linear combination of Poisson random variables). How can I numerically compute $\mathbb{P}[\min\{X_1-X_2-3,X_1-2X_2\}\leqslant0]$ without using Monte Carlo?

**What I have**

For fixed scalars $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}_+$, I computed the characteristic function of $X_1-\alpha X_2-\beta$ to be

$$
\varphi(t)=\exp\bigg[-\iota\beta{t}+\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ip_i\big(\varphi_i(t)-1\big)\bigg]
$$

where

$$
\varphi_i(t)=(1-p_i)e^{-\iota\alpha\nu_it}+p_ie^{\iota(1-\alpha\nu_i)t}.
$$

for $\iota=\sqrt{-1}$.
I can then use the Gil-Pelaez inversion formula to numerically calculate $\mathbb{P}[X_1-\alpha{X_2}-\beta\leqslant0]$ (this works quite well in practice). To calculate the minimum, I need to work out something about the joint distribution, which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Hvae you tried computing $E[e^{i(t_1X_1+t_2X_2)}]$? By inverting this you'll get $P(X_1\leq a,X_2\leq b)$, and then just use inclusion-exclusion to calculate the minimum.

Comment: @AlexR. That would be the characteristic function of the vector-valued random variable $X=(X_1,X_2)$, right? Is there an obvious or well-known extension of the GP inversion formula to the vector-valued case?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings No, it’s a stylized version of a more complex problem I encountered. If you just want to give a hint or tip, I would appreciate that too

Comment: Not that it helps much but we could write the problem more compact (and somewhat more general) as a sum of random vectors: 

$$R_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_i)$$

$$\vec{V} = \begin{bmatrix} V_1 \\ V_2 \end{bmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^n \begin{bmatrix} \nu_i \\ \xi_i \end{bmatrix} R_i $$

compute $P[V_1 \leq a \text{ or } V_2 \leq b] \equiv 1-P[V_1>a \text{ and } V_2 >b]$. I guess that you should be able to express the characteristic function for $\vec{V}$  and then use some inversion formula to perform the numeric computation.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I see, I see. That approach is similar to Alex R.’s suggestion, it seems? Might need to look more closely for some inversion theorems

Comment: Here $$\min(X_1-X_2-3,\,X_1-2X_2)=X_1-\max(X_2+3,\,2X_2).$$ This simplification might have been more obvious with better variable names, e.g. replacing $X_1$ and $X_2$ with $U$ and $V$.